# How change color/picture of specific one ListView row - Android?

Tags: android, android-listview, listactivity

I am trying to change only one (maybe more) ListView row based on specific condition. I have read many answers on similar questions and tons of other tutorials but I am not able to make anything.

Exactly what I want to achieve is to have row background (easier version) or row picture (I think harder version) set different than others when row from SQLite is set at specific value.

I have got Activity that extends ListActivity and I am setting the ListView adapter like this:

```
private void refreshList() {
    mySQLiteAdapter = new MyDBAdapter(this);
    mySQLiteAdapter.open();
    String[] columns = { MyDBAdapter.KEY_TITLE, MyDBAdapter.KEY_GENRE,
            MyDBAdapter.KEY_PRICE, MyDBAdapter.KEY_ID };

    Cursor contentRead = mySQLiteAdapter.getAllEntries(false, columns,
            null, null, null, null, MyDBAdapter.KEY_TITLE, null);

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapterCursor = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.row, contentRead, columns, new int[] {
                    R.id.text1, R.id.detail });

    this.setListAdapter(adapterCursor);
    mySQLiteAdapter.close();
}
```

This function is called in onCreate method and in onResume. I want to set different color/image of row where value from column `MyDBAdapter.KEY_PRICE` is equal to 5. The R.layout.row is my xml file with row design.

Maybe someone can help me with this? Or at least show tutorial describing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply extend SimpleCursorAdapter and override bindView():

```
public class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
        if(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDBAdapter.KEY_PRICE)) == 5)
            view.setBackgroundColor(0xff00ff00);
        else // this will be the default background color: transparent
            view.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    }
}
```

Comment: But can you tell me how I can set let say image or text instead of colour change. I wrote something like that, but it is repeated and not stand still as colour does: `if(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDBAdapter.KEY_PRICE)) == 5)
         { 
          TextView price = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.priceInfo);
          price.setText("High");
         }`

Comment: A built-in Android adapter recycles the views that it uses, so if you do not create an `else` case to restore the default conditions (like above) then the changes you made will randomly reappear. Say your ListView displays 8 full rows, the adapter will only use 9-10 row layouts, it does not create any more layouts even if there are 1000's of rows of data... If you still need me to post another example: just ask!

Comment: Thank you very much again. No I don't need any more examples, I just wasn't aware, how important is the else clause in this case. Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create your custom adapter that extends on SimpleCursorAdapter and inside that, on the method bindView, you can look if the condition you look for is accomplished and make what you want on that method.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#bindView(android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.database.Cursor)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#bindView%28android.view.View,%20android.content.Context,%20android.database.Cursor%29)

Hope to help :)